# adding a column from one dataframe to another according to shared values

Tags: dataframe, addition, primary-key

In python, I want to add a column from dataframe A to dataframe B.
But the rows should be match with the primary key.

I tried dataframeinsert() and .add but they are not doing it with regarding to primary key (id is primary key in here).

Dataframe_A:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| x | a |
| y | b |
| q | c |
| r | d |

Dataframe_B

| id | department |
| --- | --- |
| x | quality |
| q | production |
| y | hr |

result_Dataframe_A:

| id | name | department |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | a | quality |
| y | b | hr |
| q | c | production |
| r | d | - |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can try a left-sided [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), if this pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

Dataframe_A = Dataframe_A.merge(Dataframe_B, how='left')

print(Dataframe_A)
```

Output:

```
  id name  department
0  x    a     quality
1  y    b          hr
2  q    c  production
3  r    d         NaN
```

Comment: tnx so much @inquirer. that's what I need really.

Comment: @muratcanUrhan if the answer helped, then vote for it (click on the checkbox below the upper and lower triangle).

Comment: tnx for informing.
I tried, but it says "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."